# svelte how to prevent default action of reusable button component

Tags: svelte

how to prevent default action of button in side reusable button component?

My `Button.svelte` component is like this

```html
<script lang="ts">
    let className = ''
    export { className as class }
    export let type: any = 'button'
</script>

<button
    class="text-white hover:bg-blue-600 {className}"
    on:click|preventDefault
    on:focus
    on:submit
    type="{type}">
    <slot />
</button>
```

And this is how I use it

in `Contact.svelte` component

```html
import Button from '../../../lib/button.svelte'

<form>
<input type="text" name="email" />
<Button type="submit" class="mt-2">Save</Button>
</form>
```

The problem with this, when I click the button, I expect the submit happen, but it doesn't. But I also want to keep the preventDefault, Because in many case I need it.

Answer (score 2):

`preventDefault` is not a good default.

In general, if you have a form, it usually makes more sense to handle its `submit` rather than handling a button's `click`.

So I would recommend removing it from the component because it cannot be undone from the outside. You can also define a utility function that you can wrap your handler with. (As of now, this will likely be how this ought to be done in Svelte 5, which may ship such functions with the package.)

```js
function preventDefault(handler) {
  return e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handler(e);
  };
}
```

```html
<Button on:click={preventDefault(someHandler)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `preventDefault` on `on:click|preventDefault`

Works great when its remove, I tested the code in a [StackBlitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-el2npg?file=src%2Froutes%2Fbutton.svelte).

UI libraries that implement a Button.svelte won't put a `preventDefault` there, because it can't be modified in other files. See example over at SvelteStrap:

https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap/blob/master/src/Button.svelte